# Matplotlib: Line chart with different groups by each line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, analytics

For example this table:

```
list_1=[['2010','20-30',0.2],
        ['2010','31-40',0.35],
       ['2010','41-50',0.47,],
       ['2010','51-60',0.21,],
       ['2011','20-30',0.23,],
       ['2011','31-40',0.42,],
       ['2011','41-50',0.55,],
       ['2011','51-60',0.19,],
       ['2012','20-30',0.36,],
       ['2012','31-40',0.24,],
       ['2012','41-50',0.71,],
       ['2012','51-60',0.12,]]
labels=['Year','Age_group','Order_Rate']
df=pd.DataFrame(list_1,columns=labels)
df
```

Output:

```
    Year    Age_group   Order_Rate
0   2010    20-30       0.20
1   2010    31-40       0.35
2   2010    41-50       0.47
3   2010    51-60       0.21
4   2011    20-30       0.23
5   2011    31-40       0.42
6   2011    41-50       0.55
7   2011    51-60       0.19
8   2012    20-30       0.36
9   2012    31-40       0.24
10  2012    41-50       0.71
11  2012    51-60       0.12
```

I need make line chart where x_axis= Year, y_axis= Order_Rate
and each color trend line this Age_Group

Comment: `sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Year', y='Order_Rate', hue='Age_group')`

Comment: Thanks, but this output chart to simple. Do you have any solution with matplotlib  ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'too simple'?  Seaborn creates a matplotlib plot. You can use any matplotlib function to make changes and additions. `sns.lineplot` also has lots of extra parameters and supports kwargs to pass down parameters to pyplot.plot.

Comment: It returns a matplotlib axis instance. You can further customize it.